# AngularJS dynamically set class on <html> tag based on route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure the best way to approach this.

I want to dynamically set a class on my `/login` route so that my login page can have a large background image.

What is the best way to approach this?

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="SOME_DYNAMIC_CLASS_HERE_BASED_ON_ROUTE">
...
</html>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
      })
```

Comment: @wbeange the issue here is scope - can you give the OP a clearer answer on how a directive might be used on the html element? I suppose if ng-app is on the html element a directive could work there, but I've never attempted using one outside of controller scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have your `ng-app` attached in the `<html>` element, to have any sort of connection between angular and the view. Since you want something to change base on the current route of your application, then why not use those routes as a reference for your configuration, e.g. the `$routeProvider` configuration. Attach all your configuration, including configuration from classes to styles or any other configuration within the route object. You can then create a directive that listens to route changes via **[`$routeChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess)** and then get the current route and other properties using the **[`$route`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when)** object defined as the second parameter of the `$routeChangeSuccess` listener, once you have those properties, you can do whatever you want with it `e.g.` append a class to that directive element.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bcIDFNJsVFAmVKOnGsnb?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

*Configuration*

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        'class': 'bg-dashboard'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        'class': 'bg-login'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
  });
```

*Directive*

```
  .directive('classRoute', function($rootScope, $route) {

    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var previous = '';
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, currentRoute) {
        var route = currentRoute.$$route;
        if(route) {

          var cls = route['class'];

          if(previous) {
            attr.$removeClass(previous);
          }

          if(cls) {
            previous = cls;
            attr.$addClass(cls);
          }
        }
      });
    };

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp" class-route>...</html>
```

Comment: That's a better approach of how to set the class

Answer (score 0):

Using a directive is one way to go.

```
.directive("routeClass", function($location, $parse) {
    var mapping = {};
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        mapping = $parse(attrs["routeClass"])(scope);
        // do something with mapping and $location or $routeParams
      }
    }
  });

<any route-class="{'/': 'default', '/Book': 'book'}" />
```

Another - is to set it via `$rootScope`.

Comment: But can i use that outside of my ng-app and ng-controller? I don't think so, so then would I create a parent controller? Or what's the best way to handle that?

Comment: You have to use it inside `ng-app` but not necessarily inside any `ng-controller`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across it looking for some pointers. I have gone for the following method which feels more "Angular". Note, it is using a `controllerAs`-based directive:

```
ngModule.directive('routeClass', routeClass);

function routeClass($state, $log) {

    function controllerFn($scope) {

        var routeClass = this;

        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
            // I have a different class name assignment as the 
            // setup of my states is relatively complex, 
            // but this should demonstrate the idea
            routeClass.current = 'page-' + $state.current.name;
        });
    }

    return {
        controller: controllerFn,
        controllerAs: 'routeClass',
        restrict: 'A'
    };
}
```

And it is used as follows in index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" route-class ng-class="{{routeClass.current}}">
```